# Printing help? information from a function in Julia

Tags: julia

Title summarises it pretty well. Is there a simple way to remotely display the help information for a function?

```
DispHelp = function(query_string)
  # Enter help mode as you would by pressing `?` and query the given string
  print(help_text)
  return help_text
end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way to do that. The help information is taken directly from the docstrings and I don't think it can be programmatically invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be possible.

````
julia-1.2> for f in [sin, cos, tan]
              println(Base.doc(f))
           end
```
sin(x)
```

Compute sine of `x`, where `x` is in radians.

```
sin(A::AbstractMatrix)
```

Compute the matrix sine of a square matrix `A`.

If `A` is symmetric or Hermitian, its eigendecomposition ([`eigen`](@ref)) is used to compute the sine. Otherwise, the sine is determined by calling [`exp`](@ref).

# Examples

```jldoctest
julia> sin(fill(1.0, (2,2)))
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.454649  0.454649
 0.454649  0.454649
```

```
cos(x)
```

Compute cosine of `x`, where `x` is in radians.

```
cos(A::AbstractMatrix)
```

Compute the matrix cosine of a square matrix `A`.

If `A` is symmetric or Hermitian, its eigendecomposition ([`eigen`](@ref)) is used to compute the cosine. Otherwise, the cosine is determined by calling [`exp`](@ref).

# Examples

```jldoctest
julia> cos(fill(1.0, (2,2)))
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.291927  -0.708073
 -0.708073   0.291927
```

```
tan(x)
```

Compute tangent of `x`, where `x` is in radians.

```
tan(A::AbstractMatrix)
```

Compute the matrix tangent of a square matrix `A`.

If `A` is symmetric or Hermitian, its eigendecomposition ([`eigen`](@ref)) is used to compute the tangent. Otherwise, the tangent is determined by calling [`exp`](@ref).

# Examples

```jldoctest
julia> tan(fill(1.0, (2,2)))
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 -1.09252  -1.09252
 -1.09252  -1.09252
```
````

With Julia you can read the code for everything, so a few hours looking through [the source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a5bfabccd8d9c351cc3b0026992fe7314ff022db/base/docs/Docs.jl) should lead to enlightenment.

Comment: @user3303504 It's better to add your edit as a separate answer, rather than edit my answer, which attributes it to me! :)

Answer (score 1):

To complete the daycaster's answer on how to display the help for built-in function.

If you want to display help on your own function, you have to write a doc string as follow, on this example function:

```
#Here is my docstring between triple quote, just before function declaration
"""
square(x)


Return the square of x, if it's a number. If it's a vector, return element-wise square of the vector
"""
function square(x)
#And now the body of my function
       out = x.*x
end
```